# How to use Lookup when using SPS Lookup Columns?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

When I have two tables (Customer and Order) and Order has an SPS Lookup column to link to customer I can use the Lookup function in PowerApps to display customer information in a Gallery of Orders.

For example: Assuming ThisItem is an Order:
`Lookup(Customer, ID = ThisItem.Customer_Id, 'Company Name')` works just fine.

But with a One-to-Many relationship, using SPS Lists to store the relationships, I cannot get the nested lookup to work.

For Example, with the addition of a Service list and a `Ordered_Service` list, I can link an unlimited number of services to an `Order`, by storing `order_id` and `service_id` in  my SPS list using lookup columns.

But when I attempt to do lookup the `ServiceName` from an Order Gallery, I am unsuccessful

```
Lookup(Service, ID = Lookup(
      ordered_service,
      order_id = ThisItem.ID, service_id),
  Service_Name)
```

I've tried using both the `order_id.Id` and `order_id.Value` and wrapping both sides of my condition in `Text()` and always get 2 Invalid Type errors and a Delegation Warning.

I'd like to know how to properly do this Lookup and I can modify the List relationships if needed.

NOTE: I assume using SQL this would likely work better, but its not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a break. Worked out. Sat back down. figured it out.
^^ That should be a standard answer for all questions. ;-)

You have to wrap ALL the things in `Text()` AND use `.Value` on all not `.ID` (that is primary Key) fields.

```
Lookup(Service, Text(ID) = Text(Lookup(
    ordered_service,
    Text(order_id.Value) = Text(ThisItem.ID),
    service_id.Value)),
  Service_Name)
```